# Multiple Arguments of a subscriber ROS indigo, arduino, C++

Tags: c++, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey I would like to control a adruino Board using rosserial.
All works fine except when I would like to use a topic and give it two arguments I tired:

```
            //some code here
         void turn(const std_msgs::Bool& lr, const std_msgs::UInt16& angle){
           // some code here (I used here lr.data and angle.data at the right places
        }
         //some code

         // now here I get my error: because I type in here 2 arguments:
          ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Bool, std_msgs::UInt16> tur("Turn",turn);
          
        // setup(), loop() function etc. some other code
```

I already read e.g here: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers
or here: http://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber/

Now what I simply would like to do:

```
roscore, rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0,
rostopic pub Turn std_msgs/Bool??? value1, value2
```

where value1 and value2 stands I just want to execute a topic with and give it two values instead of writing two seperate topics with only one argument.

I would be very happy if someone can write a little bit more detailed answer(more specific for my problem) than in the above links.

Thank you very much! :)
Best Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234431/multiple-arguments-of-a-subscriber-ros-indigo,-arduino,-c++/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should create a custom message type that contains your two values as members:
[create ros msg](http://wiki.ros.org/msg)

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2016-05-17**:
Thanks. I thought I could come around that. But according to ahendrix not when I want to use it on arduino.